# How to set the default value in datetimepicker as previous month

Tags: vb.net, datetime, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I have my VB.net program with a `datetimepicker` and the custom format of which is `MM/yyyy`. I want the default value at application startup in the `datetimepicker` as previous month and I don't care whatever day it shows(it can be any day of previous month of the same year). Using `DateTimePicker.Value = CDate(Now.Date.AddDays(-(Now.Day)))` give me the value I want but how can I set it as the default value at application startup?

Comment: `Dim dt = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1) : myDTP.Value = dt`

Comment: (put it in form_load)

Comment: Can you explain. I am a beginner in VB.net

Comment: there is nothing to explain. 2 lines of code in the Form_Load event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer working fine. adding the following code to form load event served my purpose

```
Dim dt = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1) 
me.DateTimePicker.Value = dt
```

Thanks plutonix for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
datetimepicker1.value = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1)
```

Change the `-1` to your desired value, example

1. `-2` = 2 months previous
2. `2`  = 2 months adVance